# PHP 5.4.24 Why do function as array contents works in global name space but not within class

Tags: php, arrays, class, oop, methods

This works:

```
$someFunction = array(
   "f1" => function(){ do something}
);
```

this doesn't:

```
class CougarTown{
   public static $someFunction = array(
      "f1" => function(){ do something}
   );
}
```

Why and is there a work around?

Comment: http://www.haykranen.nl/2013/03/13/howto-use-closure-functions-as-array-values-in-a-class-in-php-5-4/ lists workarounds that I'm not pleased with but will have to do, still WHY is an interesting question.

Comment: Any sort of *non-constant expression* doesn't work to initialise class properties. I suppose closures count as a non-constant expression.

Comment: The dupe should answer *"why"*.

Comment: You're right of course but it doesn't seem sensible. closures are pretty constant. They are unnamed so it's pretty difficult to modify them later. They exist in original form or they are released from memory and replaced.

Comment: Don't try to argue with PHP on a logical level. It'll just drag you down to its own inconsistent world and beat you with experience. ;)